# Is $\log \det \left( I + \frac 1 {\sigma^2} H F \bar H \right)$ concave?

Tags: convex-optimization

I want to maximize the capacity function $\log \det \left( I + \frac 1 {\sigma^2} H F \bar H \right)$ with respect to $F$, subject to the constraints:

(1) $\operatorname{trace} F \le Pt$

(2) $\operatorname{trace} G F \bar G \le Ith$

such that:

$F$, of size $12 \times 12$, is a variable complex hermitian positive definite matrix

$I$, of size $6 \times 6$, is the identity matrix

$H$, of size $6 \times 12$, is a constant matrix

$G$ of size $3 \times 12$, is a constant matrix

$\sigma, Pt, Ith$ are scalar constants.

Is the given function convex in $F$? If not, how to make it so?

Comment: what is $\bar{H}$?

Comment: the Hermitian of the matrix H

Comment: you mean the conjugate transpose?

Comment: yes it is the conjugate transpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note your terminology error. You asked if the *function* was convex--but you gave us an entire optimization *model*. You should be asking instead if your model is a convex *optimization problem*, not a convex *function*. And in fact, your objective function is *concave*---but it needs to be. So it's all the more important to get that terminology correct.

The logarithm of the determinant of a symmetric matrix is concave. Your objective function is just the composition of the logdet function with an affine function of $F$, therefore it is concave as well. Thus you may *maximize* it in a convex optimization setting, as you have done. (Equivalently, you may minimize its negative, as its negative is convex.)

Both of your constraints are simple linear inequalities, and therefore convex as well.

Comment: thank you very much for this answer but i want to bring you to the case under my hands as you have so much experience with the software package CVX. I have made a code and asked you a question in the CVX forum

I will enclose the link here and it will be great if you inform me about the unbounded output that i am getting:

http://ask.cvxr.com/t/why-do-i-keep-receiving-an-unbounded-optimal-value-for-this-cvx-optimization-issue/3244